# Format chart value from 20 decimal places to no decimal places

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a line graph to show monthly % data on the y-axis.

Can I format the value shown to show as a %? At the moment I'm seeing figures like 0.9335180054409484 - not much use.

This value is showing from an expression:

=Sum(Fields!Under20minutes.Value / Count(Fields!xno.Value) - which gives me the correct number - it's just I want it formatted as a %.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just right-click on the series labels in your chart, and click on Series Label Properties. Go to "Number", and change to %, choose decimal places, etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried that, but just get the options from 'delete series' to 'series properties' - no 'series label properties', unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, just realised I had to right-click on one of the data labels to get 'series label properties'. Thanks.